# FZR 600 not cranking

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha, no-crank-no-start

I have a 94 FZR600 that won't crank. Here are the symptoms. After turning on the ignition switch, all lights come on as expected. When I press the starter button, the headlights dim, and the starter motor is not being engaged. I also don't hear the fuel pump.

The other odd behavior is that the right side indicators flash much faster than the left one. Not sure if the two issues are related.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you fully charged and tested the battery? When was the battery last replaced? As I don't think it will be the original....

Comment: Hi @solar mike. Yes, I have. I also ran the same test with a different, known good battery. I got the same results.

Comment: Has a ground cable been left unconnected? Are all the connections and cables in good condition?

Comment: So far yes, but I'm still checking. The main ground connector is attached to the engine block and looks solid.

Comment: it's not the starter relay. I managed to get the bike cranking by connecting the relay wire from the starter button to ground.

Comment: I think one of your safety featured failed. Can you try starting the bike on neutral? If the same happens then it is not the clutch lever or sidestand "detectors". It may still be your kill switch (the red button on the right thumb). Maybe there is some sort of corasion or dust is causing it to behave like it is "on" when it should be "off". (sorry for the caveman terminology.)

Comment: Turns out the starter button is broken.